# How to simplify creating huge data structures in Python

Tags: python, data-structures

I am writing some and I need to pass a complicated data structure to some function.

The data structure goes like this:

```
{ 'animals': [ 'cows', 'moose', { 'properties': [ 9, 26 ] } ]
  'fruits': {
    'land': [ 'strawberries', 'other berries' ],
    'space': [ 'apples', 'cherries' ]
  }
}
```

This structure looks pretty ugly to me. Can you think of ways how to simplify writing such massive data structures?

PS. I made up this structure but my real structure is very similar tho.

Comment: What's wrong with it?  A dictionary of lists and dictionaries has no real problem with it.  What are you concerned?  What's wrong with it?

Comment: you have to describe your program in more detail. Are the properties `[9, 26]` the properties of the animals?

Comment: ` [ 'cows', 'moose', { 'properties': [ 9, 26 ] } ]` is undesireable. Lists gain power when all the elements share the same type (or at least the same duck-typable properties).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Other languages would solve this problem with objects or structs-- so, something like:

```
class whatever:
    animals = AnimalObject()
    fruits = FruitObject()

class AnimalObject:
    animals = ['cows','moose']
    properties = [9,26]

class FruitObject:
    land = ['strawberries', 'other berries']
    space = ['apples', 'cherries']
```

Of course, this only works if you know ahead of time what form the data is going to take. If you don't, then maps/lists are your only choice ;-)

Answer (score 2):

1. Use objects. You are working with basic types like strings and dictionaries while objects are more powerful.
2. Use function arguments. You can pass the the first-level keys in your dictionary as arguments to your function:

```
def yourfunction(animals, fruits)
    # do things with fruits and animals
    pass
```

Comment: Or he can leave his structure as it is and pass it as `yourfunction(*his_variable)`

Comment: @voyager less expressive in my opinion